# Ansible copy does not retain original permissions with mode "preserve" when using remote_src

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using Ansible `2.8.5` (and the target servers are Red Hat `4.8.5-39`). I'm copying some files/directories from GitLab into several remote hosts.

I'm doing an initial copy first into a shared location (hence the `run_once: true`):

```
- name: "Copy/Transfer application, configuration, and support file(s)"
  block:
    - name: "Copying application build"
      copy:
        dest: "{{ path_tmp }}/{{ CI_PIPELINE_ID }}/"
        mode: "0755"
        src: "{{ CI_PROJECT_DIR }}/build/libs/{{ artifact_id }}.war"
      run_once: true
    - name: "Copying (template) configuration and support file(s)"
      template:
        dest: "{{ path_tmp }}/{{ CI_PIPELINE_ID }}/{{ item.dest }}"
        mode: "0644"
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
      run_once: true
      with_items:
        - { dest: "config/logback.xml", src: "logback.xml.j2" }
        - { dest: "{{ artifact_id }}.conf", src: "{{ artifact_id }}.conf.j2" }
```

...and then copying the files into the desired location on each host:

```
- name: "Deploy/Install new application"
  block:
    # All this Jiu Jitsu just to clear {{ path_home }}/ directory
    - name: "Collecting current directories and/or files inside {{ path_home }}/"
      find:
        file_type: any
        hidden: yes
        paths: "{{ path_home }}/"
      register: collected_items
    - name: "Removing current directories and/or files inside {{ path_home }}/"
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ collected_items.files }}"
    - name: "Copying new application, configuration, and support files"
      copy:
        dest: "{{ path_home }}/"
        mode: preserve
        remote_src: yes
        src: "{{ path_tmp }}/{{ CI_PIPELINE_ID }}/"
    ...
```

The problem is that files permissions are not getting "honored", and I wouldn't like to have to define several steps to correct that. This is how the files/directories are getting copied initially (and how I want them):

```sh
[deployer@unix core]$ ll -AR 41397/
41397/:
total 51M
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat 1.2K Oct 11 11:23 core.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 tomcat  50M Oct 11 11:23 core.war

41397/config:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat 1.6K Oct 11 11:23 logback.xml
```

...and this is how they look like after the copy using `remote_src: yes`:

```sh
[deployer@unix core]$ ll -AR /data/st01/apps/core/
/data/st01/apps/core/:
total 50M
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat 4.0K Oct  9 16:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 config
-rw-r-----. 1 tomcat 1.2K Oct 11 11:23 core.conf
-rw-r-----. 1 tomcat  50M Oct 11 11:23 core.war

/data/st01/apps/core/config:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat 4.0K Oct 11 11:23 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat 1.6K Oct 11 11:23 logback.xml
```

Is it possible to use `remote_src: yes` and retain original file/directories permissions? The documentation for the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) says so, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into this exact scenario today (remote source, recursive copy of directories, mode=preserve specified) on Ansible 2.9.6 but getting the files with reset permissions (masked by umask of course).

Comment: Well, since I don't have tons of files, I ended up using the `synchronize` module.

Comment: I actually had just one file in the directory, so ended up copying that file to a directory target -- which makes the directory if it doesn't exist. And the permissions are preserved correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution for me was using the `synchronize` module **because I don't have a lot of files** to copy/move:

```yaml
- name: "Copy latest application build, configuration, and support file(s)"
  synchronize:
    delete: yes
    dest: "{{ app_path }}/latest/"
    recursive: yes
    src: "{{ tmp_path }}/{{ PIPELINE_ID }}/"
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this while searching for a solution.  Pointed me in the correct direction which was the ansible file page ([ansible doc site](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)).  To sum up you delare state, recurse if you need it.  That should perserve the permissions you have at source for dest.

```
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /home/user/dir1
    dest: /data_dir/
    remote_src: yes
    state: directory. #<---- Should allow the permissions to follow the copy
    recurse: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

ansible document says

remote_src supports recursive copying as of version [2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html).
remote_src only works with mode=preserve as of version [2.6](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/copy_module.html)

you either need to downgrade your system to ansible 2.6, or else try giving 'mode' with required permissions (like 0644 or 01777)

Comment: I get that, but I would assume that regardless, if I specify `mode: preserve` it will honor that setting, right?